# UPS API to get Shipping and Delivery details

Tags: ups

I am trying to integrate UPS QuantumView API to get shipping and delivery details for a particular time range (last 6 days starting from today), but it looks like my script is completely ignoring the DateTimeRange and displaying all the shipment details starting from 2001. My xml is:

```
 $startDate = date("YmdHms", strtotime("now -6 day")); 
 $endDate = date("YmdHms", strtotime("now"));

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <AccessLicenseNumber>XXXXXXXXXX</AccessLicenseNumber>
  <UserId>XXXXXX</UserId>
  <Password>XXXXXXX</Password>
</AccessRequest>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QuantumViewRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <Request>
    <RequestAction>QVEvents</RequestAction>
  </Request>
  <SubscriptionRequest>
    <DateTimeRange>
        <BeginDateTime>'.$startDate.'</BeginDateTime>
        <EndDateTime>'.$endDate.'</EndDateTime>
    </DateTimeRange>
  </SubscriptionRequest>
</QuantumViewRequest>
```

Can anyone help me in pointing out where I am wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you select what subscription you want.

```
    <SubscriptionRequest>
       <Name>Your subscription name</Name>
       <DateTimeRange>
```

Make sure the quantum view subscription is setup to be in xml format.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but what exactly is a Subscription Name, is that like the name of a service, an account, or the actual data call you're attempting to make?

Comment: It should be a title of the report in one the admin panels. The three I use (which may or may not be similar to yours) ['Company Outbound','Company Inbound', 'Company Third Party'].      Looking through the ups control panel, i cant even find them.

Comment: Under your username on ups.com - Quantum view admistration -> Access quantum view data -> then clicking on any of the following
'Outbound Subscriptions', 'Inbound Receiving Addresses Subscriptions', 'Third Party Subscriptions'. Once there you will see that particular name

Comment: Really awesome, thanks- just wondering as a next step, I'm using the json api w/ "SubscriptionRequest": {"Name": "devicesinbound","DateTimeRange": {"BeginDateTime":"20171107000000","EndDateTime":"20171108000000"}} as a way to get all inbound to be delivered on a specific day- any advice on what would actually work? I'm getting items delivered outside out that date range which makes it seem like there's clearly more correct attributes to use